# PHP Laravel 5.3 questions

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, permissions, routes

I have searched for information about two issues I am trying to solve, but I have not been able to get a clear idea of how to fix it. Specially, for Laravel 5.3 a lot of things have changed and there is less information than with previous versions.

- My first question is: I need to show different views depending if I am using a PC or a mobile device. How I could solve it?
- My second question is: How can I modify the routes and redirects in the web.php file? For example:

  - If a user is an "admin", first I need to be able to get that parameter (don't know how to do it in the routes) and in the case that it is true, redirect to the adminpanel view. In other case, redirect to the home view.
  - In the same way, if a non-admin person try to access to the view (for example, he knows the path) of the admin panel, he should be redirect to the home screen.

Thank you so much for your help.

Have a nice day and best regards.

Jose Lara.

Comment: 1 question per question please http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, sorry.
I am going to write botth questions separately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is the answer of your second question.

> how to redirect unauthorized person or a subscriber to the login or to
>   the unrestricted pages or we can say to the pages that everyone can
>   access.

in **AdminController**  don't forgot to use the **use Auth;**

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('admin);
}
public function index()
{ 
  return view('adminpanelview');
}

in **HomeController**
public function index()
{ 
  return view('homeview');
}
**Web.php** route will be like 

Route::get('/Admin',['uses'=>'AdminCotroller@index','as'=>'admin']);
Route::get('/home',['uses'=>'homeCotroller@index','as'=>'home']);

in **Admin.php** we should put the below code 
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if(!Auth::user()->admin)
  { 
   return redirect()->route('home');
   //return to non
  }
  return $next($request);
}
 in **Kernel.php** **protected $routeMiddleware** we should register this middleware
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class
```

Answer (score -1):

your number 1 question has to do with the blade template(view) i guess. if am correct, then blade template (view) has to do with bootstrap integration. what you are asking, bootstrap mobile view can handle that for you. goto [https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_default&stacked=h][1] you will have a better understanding of what you want.

Comment: Bootstrap isn't required with Laravel, and you can do responsive design with a lot more than just Bootstrap.

Comment: however, on your blade you can load bootstrap files using asset('')